# Is there a way to automatically align function arguments?

Tags: rstudio

In RStudio is there a way to automatically align the equal signs in function arguments?

Similar to the following:

```
objective         = obj,
eta               = params$eta[i],
gamma             = params$gamma[i],
max_depth         = params$max_depth[i],
colsample_bytree  = params$colsample_bytree[i],
colsample_bylevel = params$colsample_bylevel[i],
lambda            = params$lambda[i],
alpha             = params$alpha[i],
subsample         = params$subsample[i])
```

I find this much easier to read. If it is not available in RStudio is there a different editor which has this capability?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution in the AlignAssign RStudio addin: https://github.com/seasmith/AlignAssign

Answer (score 2):

Another option is [{remedy}](https://thinkr-open.github.io/remedy/), which is also on [CRAN](https://cloud.r-project.org/web/packages/remedy/index.html).

That package include addins for aligning equal signs `=` and assignments `<-`, plus other addins for working with markdown documents.